# Russian output in Visual Studios c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to make a Vocabulary trainer for People who want to learn Russian. I typed everything in russian but when i try to run the code the russian is replaced with ?. Can anybody help me??[image: russian output]

i want that the english text above is also in russian a line under it.

Comment: You can try setting the OutputEncoding property to Console. For example: Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Comment: Hi,@notfound.Did the answer solve your problem? If so, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `OutputEncoding` property of `Console`:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```